# optimal way to debug zsh competion functions

Tags: zsh

When we run `compinit`, it redefines all the widgets which perform completion.

If I am working on a completion function, I can just use `rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit` to see how my new completion function is working.

However, I think there is a more efficient way to do it.

Suppose I wrote the following completion function from [zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org#writing-simple-completion-functions-using-_describe)

```
#compdef cmd
local -a subcmds
subcmds=('c:description for c command' 'd:description for d command')
_describe 'command' subcmds
```

How can I quickly modify small part of the function and see how the function is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's never any need to rerun `compinit`. You can use `compdef` to define your new completion function provided it can be found in `$fpath`, for example:

```
    compdef -a _cmd cmd
```

The `-a` marks `_cmd` for autoloading.

I tend to work in a temporary directory or local git checkout so define the following alias to quickly add the current directory to the start of `$fpath`:

```
    alias -- +fpath='fpath=( ~+ $fpath)'
```

It can also be useful to reload autoloadable functions when you've modified them. For this I have the following function which also removes functions that were defined in the function:

```
freload() {
  local func
  for func; do
    unfunction ${(k)functions_source[(R)${functions_source[$func]:-X(#s)}]:-$func};
    autoload -U $func;
  done
}
```

Another thing I do is I have `compdef _foo foo` already defined in my `.zshrc` which makes it very quick and easy to test things out just by defining an `_foo` function directly on the command-line.